# Adding constraints on view which is on scroll view is showing exception

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am using auto layout technique to design a view.I have done auto layout with scroll bar so many times. But today I am getting a wierd exception.

**Exception**

```
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:]: A multiplier of 0 or a nil second item together with a location for the first attribute creates an illegal constraint of a location equal to a constant. Location attributes must be specified in pairs'
```

**I have not added any multiplier with zero then why it is showing this exception**

**Code:**

```
-(void)allocScrollVieww:(UIView*)Mview
{

    scrll=[UIScrollView new];
    [scrll setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [Mview addSubview:scrll];


    SBV=[UIView new];
    [SBV setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];// as i can't add constraints on `scrollView` so I have added a view on `scrollView` 
    [scrll addSubview:SBV];

}

-(void)scrllView:(UIView*)Mview
{

    [Mview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:scrll attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:Mview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1 constant:0]];


    [Mview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:scrll attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:Mview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1 constant:0]];


    [Mview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:scrll attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:Mview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:0]];

    [Mview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:scrll attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:Mview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:0]];


    [scrll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(Mview.frame.size.width, Mview.frame.size.height+100)];


    [SBV setFrame:CGRectMake(scrll.frame.origin.x, scrll.frame.origin.y, scrll.frame.size.width, scrll.frame.size.height+100)];


-(void)BuyotherView:(UIView*)views
{
  //green label
    UILabel *greebLabel1=[UILabel new];
    [greebLabel1 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [greebLabel1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:0.2 alpha:0.3]];
    [views addSubview:greebLabel1];

    [views addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:greebLabel1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:views attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];


    [views addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:greebLabel1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:views attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];

    [views addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:greebLabel1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:navBar attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom  multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];

    [views addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:greebLabel1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:navBar attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:0.5 constant:0]];


- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [self allocScrollVieww:self.view];
    [self scrllView:self.view];
    [self BuyotherView:SBV];
    [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No answer! No problem I found the solutions myself.

**Code**

```
-(void)BuyotherView:(UIView*)views
{
  //green label
    UILabel *greebLabel1=[UILabel new];
    [greebLabel1 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [greebLabel1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:0.2 alpha:0.3]];
    [views addSubview:greebLabel1];

    [views addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:greebLabel1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:views attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];


    [views addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:greebLabel1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:views attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];

    [views addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:greebLabel1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:navBar attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom  multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];
//navBar is associated to other view. And it is illegal to use constarint of one UIVIew object of one view to another.
    [views addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:greebLabel1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:navBar attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:0.5 constant:0]];
```

I changed last constraint as:

```
 [views addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:greebLabel1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:0 constant:44*0.7]];
```

And it started working fine :)